# How to access data from foreign key table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select, join

I have three tables Company, User , Address .
 **company** has three fields

- comp_id(PK)
- comp_name
- user_id(FK)
- to_address_id(FK)
- from_address_id(FK)

  **Address** has fields:
- address_id(PK)
- city
- state

  User has fields
  user_id(PK),user_name

  to_address_id and from_address_id both are foreign key which references same table Address and maps to address_id

  now the point is how to retreive the from_address from the table , I am able to retrieve the to_address from this query.

  Here i can get both the to_address_id and from_address_id from the Shipment table but how to get both the addresses in the same query based on the address_id:

> ```
>  SELECT s.comp_name,u.user_name,a.city
>             FROM
>         company s
>     JOIN
>         User u
>     JOIN
>         Address a
>     ON
>         s.user_id = u.user_id 
>         AND s.to_address_id = a.address_id
>     WHERE
>         s.user_id = 1001;
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution - you need to JOIN two times, each for every FK you're interested in:

```
SELECT s.comp_name, u.user_name, a_from.city AS city_from, a_to.city AS city_to
FROM company s
LEFT JOIN User u ON s.user_id = u.user_id 
LEFT JOIN Address a_from ON s.from_address_id = a_from.address_id
LEFT JOIN Address a_to ON s.to_address_id = a_to.address_id
WHERE s.user_id = 1001;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
 SELECT s.comp_name
        ,u.user_name
        ,a1.city
        ,a2.city 
 FROM company s 
 JOIN User u ON s.user_id = u.user_id  
 JOIN Address a1 ON s.to_address_id = a1.address_id 
 JOIN Address a2 ON s.from_address_id = a2.address_id
 WHERE s.user_id = 1001;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to first look into the use **JOIN** in query.

Try this:

```
SELECT s.comp_name,u.user_name,a.city
FROM company s
JOIN User u ON s.user_id = u.user_id 
JOIN Address a ON s.to_address_id = a.address_id
WHERE s.user_id = 1001;
```